# How to add linebreak to textContent in $mdDialog

Tags: angularjs

I want to add line break in .textcontent of mdDiaglog.
Following is my code:

```
var confirm = $mdDialog.confirm()
        .title('Refresh')
        .textContent('Some information will be lost.'+'<br>'+ 'Do you want to refresh?')
        .targetEvent(ev)
        .ok('YES')
        .cancel('NO');
  $mdDialog.show(confirm).then(function () {
          $window.location.reload();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use .htmlContent().

> $mdDialogPreset#textContent(string) - Sets the confirm message.
>   $mdDialogPreset#htmlContent(string) - Sets the confirm message as HTML. Requires ngSanitize module to be loaded. HTML is not run through Angular's compiler.

[Documentation](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdDialog)

Comment: [Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize) for ngSanitize

Answer (score 7):

In order to accomplish this task you will need to install `angular-sanitize.js`. This js can be downloaded from [here](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular-sanitize.min.js). After downloading, link that to your project after loading angularJS.

```
<head>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/sanitize/sangular-sanitize.js"></script>
</head>
```

Since this is a provider you need to be instantiated and wired in the module together for the app to work. Following JS shows how to inject the provider.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial','ngMessages', 'ngSanitize']);
    var baseUrl = 'http://localhost:54037/Home/'
</script>
```

After that you can use .htmlContent in the code as follows

```
$mdDialog.show(
$mdDialog.alert()
    .clickOutsideToClose(true)
    .title('Your Tile')
    .htmlContent("<h1>html</h1><h4>works</h4>")
    .ok('Okay!')
);
```

Answer (score 2):

write css class in your styles and use '\n' instead of `<br>` in textContent()

```
.md-dialog-content-body p{
   white-space: pre;
 }
```